# How to use protocol oriented programming to improve my Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-oriented

I have a rather large project structured in this format:

```
class One : FirstThree {

    fileprivate var integers: [Int] {
        return [1, 2, 3, 101, 102]
    }

    override func allIntegers() -> [Int] {
        return integers
    }

    func doStuffForOne() {
        //does stuff unrelated to the other classes
    }
}

class Two : FirstThree {

    fileprivate var integers: [Int] {
        return [1, 2, 3, 201]
    }

    override func allIntegers() -> [Int] {
        return integers
    }

    func doStuffForTwo() {
        //does stuff unrelated to the other classes
    }
}

class Three : Numbers {

    fileprivate var integers: [Int] {
        return [301, 302, 303]
    }

    override func allIntegers() -> [Int] {
        return integers
    }

    func doStuffForThree() {
        //does stuff unrelated to the other classes
    }
}

class FirstThree : Numbers {

    fileprivate var integers: [Int] {
        return [1, 2, 3]
    }

    override func allIntegers() -> [Int] {
        return integers
    }

    func doStuffForFirstThree() {
        //does stuff unrelated to the other classes
    }
}

class Numbers {

    func allIntegers() -> [Int] {
        fatalError("subclass this")
    }

    func printMe() {
        allIntegers().forEach({ print($0) })
    }
}
```

`Numbers` has many methods like `printMe()` which I want any instance of all my subclasses to be able to call.

`Numbers` also has an `allIntegers()` function which I want any instance of these subclasses to be able to call.  Which would probably be better as a variable right?  But I can't override variables in a subclass.  So instead I use the same private variable `integers` in each subclass, which is read and returned by `allIntegers()`.

Also notice an instance of `Numbers` itself should never call `allIntegers()`, it should only be called on a subclass.

Last, notice some of the subclasses contain the same objects `1, 2, 3` and then each has some custom integers.  But not all the subclasses.  If I later decide that all those subclasses need a `4` integer, I have to manually go through each class and punch in a `4` into the array, which is obviously error prone.

I've read up on protocol oriented programming and feel like a solution might lie in there, or I'd appreciate any other suggestions and creative approaches to architecting a better project.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

All subclasses are different because they also have their own functions to perform.  I've updated the code to reflect this.

Imagine, a given class like `One` is initialized many time throughout the code base, and is always initialized with the exact same `integers`.  Putting:

```
let one = One(integers: [1, 2, 3, 101, 102])
```

All throughout the code base would be error prone.

Hopefully this resolves some of the concerns of the contrived example I've put forward.

**SOLUTION**

Thank you everyone for your help.  Here is the solution I came up with (please assume that all classes have their own unique methods).

```
class One : FirstThree {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.integers = super.integers + [101, 102]
    }
}

class Two : FirstThree {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.integers = super.integers + [201]
    }
}

class Three : Numbers {
    var integers  = [301, 302, 303]
}

class FirstThree : Numbers {
    let integers = [1, 2, 3]
}

protocol Numbers {
    var integers: [Int] { get }
    func printMe()
}

extension Numbers {
    func printMe() {
        integers.forEach({ print($0) })
    }
}
```

Comment: You defined 4 times the same class (`One`, `Two`, `Three` and `Four`). They have the exact same logic. Is there a valid reason for that?

Comment: It is Swift convention to start all your variables names with a lowercase letter

Comment: And the `_objects` property does not contains objects. `Int` is not an object, is a value.

Comment: And again, the `_objects` computed property and the `objects()` function do exactly the same thing. Why this duplication of code?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone, I've updated my example to make it seem more realistic.  Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a protocol with your common operations, including the `objects` accessor:

```
protocol Numbers {

    /// My objects. By default, `Numbers.commonObjects`. Subclasses can override to include more objects.
    var objects: [Int] { get }

    func printMeThatConformersCanOverride()

}
```

Provide default implementations in an extension:

```
extension Numbers {

    /// The default implementation of `objects`, which just returns `Numbers_defaultObjects`.
    var objects: [Int] { return Numbers_defaultObjects }

    /// Since this is declared in the protocol, conformers can override it.
    func printMeThatConformersCanOverride() {
        Swift.print("Numbers " + objects.map({ "\($0)" }).joined(separator: " "))
    }

}

/// It would be nice to make this a member of `Numbers`, but Swift won't let us.
private let Numbers_defaultObjects = [1, 2, 3]
```

Because those definitions implement things declared in the protocol, conforming types can override them. You can also define things in an extension that conforming types cannot override:

```
extension Numbers {

    /// Since this is not declared in the protocol, conformers cannot override it. If you have a value of type `Numbers` and you call this method on it, you get this version.
    func printMeThatConformersCannotOverride() {
        Swift.print("Numbers " + objects.map({ "\($0)" }).joined(separator: " "))
    }

}
```

We can then implement a class that conforms to the protocol. We can use a `let` to override `objects`:

```
class One: Numbers {

    /// You can use a `let` to override `objects`.
    let objects: [Int] = Numbers_defaultObjects + [101, 102]

    func doStuffForOne() {
        Swift.print("I'm doing One-specific stuff with \(objects)")
    }

    func printMeThatConformersCanOverride() {
        Swift.print("One wins! You don't care what type I am.")
    }

    func printMeThatConformersCannotOverride() {
        Swift.print("One wins! You think I'm type One, not type Numbers.")
    }

}
```

We can use a stored property to override `objects`:

```
class Two: Numbers {

    /// You can use a stored property to override `objects`.
    var objects: [Int] = Numbers_defaultObjects + [201]

    func doStuffForTwo() {
        Swift.print("I'm doing Two-specific stuff with \(objects)")
    }

}
```

We can use a computed property to override `objects`:

```
class Three: Numbers {

    /// You can use a computed property to override `objects`.
    var objects: [Int] { return [301, 302, Int(arc4random())] }

    func doStuffForThree() {
        Swift.print("I'm doing Three-specific stuff with \(objects)")
    }

}
```

We don't even have to use a class type. We can use a struct type instead:

```
struct Four: Numbers {
    func doStuffForFour() {
        Swift.print("I'm doing Four-specific stuff with \(objects)")
    }
}
```

I said above that you can define things in an extension and if they weren't declared in the protocol, then conforming types can't override them. This can be a bit confusing in practice. What happens if you try, like `One` does, to override a method that was defined in an extension but isn't part of the protocol?

```
let one = One()

one.printMeThatConformersCanOverride()
// output: One wins! You don't care what type I am.

(one as Numbers).printMeThatConformersCanOverride()
// output: One wins! You don't care what type I am.

one.printMeThatConformersCannotOverride()
// output: One wins! You think I'm type One, not type Numbers.

(one as Numbers).printMeThatConformersCannotOverride()
// output: Numbers 1 2 3 101 102
```

For methods declared in the protocol, you run the version belonging to the *run-time* type of the value. For methods not declared in the protocol, you run the version belonging to the *compile-time* type of the value.

Answer (score 4):

### Update

Given the new information you added to your question here's a possible approach

I really could't resist so I slightly refactored the naming :D

Now you have a protocol

```
protocol HasIntegers {
    var integers: [Int] { get }
    func printMe()
}
```

and a protocol extension which add the printMe function.

```
extension HasIntegers {
    func printMe() {
        integers.forEach { print($0) }
    }
}
```

Finally you have 2 classes (it's 4 classes in your code but the idea doesn't change).

The class A always contain `[1, 2, 3, 101, 102]` and has it's own set of methods (`doSomething()`)

```
class A: HasIntegers {
    fileprivate (set) var integers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 101, 102]
    func doSomething() { }
}
```

The class `B` always contain [1, 2, 3, 201] and has a different set of methods (`doSomethingElse()`)

```
class B: HasIntegers {
    fileprivate (set) var integers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 201]
    func doSomethingElse() { }
}
```

Both A and B conform to HasInteger and then automatically receive the `printMe()` method.

---

> OLD ANSWER

### You don't need that

I see lots of stuff in your code:

- inheritance
- <strike>protocols</strike> (well there are no protocols indeed :D)
- computed properties
- functions
- classes (lots of them!)

But there is no apparent reason for using all these things :)

### You can simply write

```
class Box {
    fileprivate (set) var integers: [Int]

    init(integers:[Int]) {
        self.integers = integers
    }

    func printMe() {
        integers.forEach { print($0) }
    }
}

let one = Box(integers: [1, 2, 3, 101, 102])
let two = Box(integers: [1, 2, 3, 201])
let three = Box(integers: [1, 2, 3, 301, 302, 303])
let four = Box(integers: [401, 402])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer.  I've updated my example to make it seem more realistic.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Misunderstood, but to prevent it from getting error prone you can use an enumerator for the types. See my appendix to @appzYourLife below.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a far complex app, and these simple classes with some dummy functions are just an easy example. So this is a way how it could be refactored using protocols:

First step can be to change the `Numbers` base class to a protocol with default implementation, like:

```
class One : Numbers {

    fileprivate var _objects: [Int] {
        return [1, 2, 3, 101, 102]
    }

    func objects() -> [Int] {
        return _objects
    }
}

class Two : Numbers {

    fileprivate var _objects: [Int] {
        return [1, 2, 3, 201]
    }

    func objects() -> [Int] {
        return _objects
    }
}

class Three : Numbers {

    fileprivate var _objects: [Int] {
        return [1, 2, 3, 301, 302, 303]
    }

    func objects() -> [Int] {
        return _objects
    }
}

class Four : Numbers {

    fileprivate var _objects: [Int] {
        return [401, 402]
    }

    func objects() -> [Int] {
        return _objects
    }
}

protocol Numbers {
    func objects() -> [Int];
    func printMe() ;
}

//Default implementation of the services of Numbers.
extension Numbers {
    func objects() -> [Int] {
        fatalError("subclass this")
    }

    func printMe() {
        objects().forEach({ print($0) })
    }
}
```

Then let's create a variable from `objects()`, as you said in your question (at this case `objects` is read-only, you cannot update it in an instance):

```
class One : Numbers {

    //Protocol specifying only the getter, so it can be both `let` and `var` depending on whether you want to mutate it later or not :
    let objects = [1, 2, 3, 101, 102]

}

class Two : Numbers {

    var objects =  [1, 2, 3, 201]

}

class Three : Numbers {

    var objects  = [1, 2, 3, 301, 302, 303]

}

class Four : Numbers {

    let objects = [401, 402]

}

protocol Numbers {

    var objects:[Int] { get }
    func printMe() ;
}

//Default implementation of the services of Numbers.
extension Numbers {

    func printMe() {
        objects.forEach({ print($0) })
    }
}
```

If the `objects` can be read-only, you can still add a default implementation for `objects` getter, like:

```
class Four : Numbers {

}

protocol Numbers {

    var objects:[Int] { get }
    func printMe() ;
}

//Default implementation of the services of Numbers.
extension Numbers {

    var objects: [Int] {
        return [401, 402]
    }

    func printMe() {
        objects.forEach({ print($0) })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, I didn't understand that a default implementation could be used by extending the protocol.  That solves part of my problem.  I've updated my question to be more specific on the rest.  `One` inherits from `FirstThree` which inherits from `Numbers`.  I'm trying to state that in `One` `let integers = super.integers + [101, 102]` which I can't do.